# Elobaration on: Discrete returns versus log returns of assets

Tags: economics, log-returns

I read [Discrete returns versus log returns of assets](https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/4160/discrete-returns-versus-log-returns-of-assets) and it is very helpful.

However, if log-returns are easier for time-aggregation, then why do economists work with discrete returns e.g. in GDP growth?

Comment: Because in the GDP case, it doesn't make sense to subdivide your time into intervals much shorter than say a quarter. Unless, you look at very long time periods, this doesn't approximate well by a continuous scheme.

Comment: @Raskolnikov: well that makes it useful for very long time periods I would say ?  Shouldn't the sum of quarterly growths equal annual growth ?  And let's say that GDP goes from 100 in year 1 to 110 in year 2 and back to 100 in year 3 then growth from year 1 to year 2 is +10% while from year 2 to year 3 it is -9.1%, would it be ''nicer'' if these growth numbers were ''symmetric'' ?