# Log returns vs normal returns with weekly prices

Tags: equities, time-series, portfolio-optimization, log-returns

I am constructing equity factors and I am given **weekly prices** for several thousand stocks. Every year the portfolio should be rebalanced, so I am always calculating the returns for a single year. Now I am unsure, whether to use normal returns: $$\prod (\frac{Price_{t}}{Price_{t-1}}) -1$$
or log returns for that matter: $$\sum \ln \frac{Price_{t}}{Price_{t-1}}$$

As far as I know, log returns are normally used for daily returns, since the deviations are not as high, since when I use it on weekly returns, the discrepancy between both methods is quite significant.
I appreciate any feedback.

Kind regards,
semicolon

Comment: See here https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/4160/discrete-returns-versus-log-returns-of-assets